# Should enhanced for loops include a function returning a list

Tags: java, for-loop

I was just concerned about enhanced for loops calling a method directly. 
Nested inside the code is my question in capital letters:

```
public class ExtendedForLoop {

    public static List<Integer> returnList() {
        System.out.println("Hurray ----> ");
        List<Integer> abc = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        abc.add(5);
        abc.add(10);
        abc.add(20);
        return abc;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (Integer i : returnList()) { // <----- OPTION 1. Include function call in extended loop.
            System.out.println(i);
        }

        List<Integer> list  = returnList()
        for (Integer i : list) { // <----- OPTION 2. Provide list to function call.
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I prefer option 2, as some exception can be dealt with.
However if no exceptions are expected then option 1 can reduce unnecessary declaration of a new variable, hence reducing clutter.

But,
In general.

1. Which option is preferred ?
2. If it is option2 and the only reason for chosing option2 is handling exceptions, then should we use option1  if no exceptions are expected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using option 1 if I'm the owner of the code that returns the list and can guarantee that null will never be returned.

If I'm not the owner, I prefer to use a different construct though

```
for(Integer i : guaranteeCollection(resultList())
{
// dostuff
}
```

```
public static <T> Collection<T> guaranteeCollection(Collection<T> c)
{
    return c != null ? c : Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

This avoids creating unnecessary variable declarations in your code and prevent NPEs.

Answer (score 1):

I think second approach with `null` check is safer.

enhanced for loop will through `NullPointerException` if method returns `null`.

Comment: Unless you're dealing with code that is out of your control, returning `null` in a method that returns a `Collection` is really ugly!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your system design:

Many project targets avoiding null objects.

If you are sure that `returnList()` will never return `null` (It should return an empty list instead (or `Collections.emptyList`), then  go for solution 1, other wise for 2.

Answer (score -2):

Well if you are dealing with **NullpointerException** in case then i prefer going with Option 1 as we are making an **extra variable** "list" on the **stack** which will occupy some memory also will reduce the performance by some bit.

Comment: I am not downvoter. Variables on "stack" is one of the things we need to worry least I guess. They will be gone as soon method done.

Comment: Yeah @Nambari dats why i said if he is dealing with nullpointerexception then both option 1 and 2 are same.We should try to minimize the creation of unnecessary variables as far as possible.